# Correct way to request Transfer Encoding chunked

Tags: java, http

I am working on an HTTP Server which currently supports non-streaming response. Now, I want to support chunked encoding as well. But to guarantee safety I don't want to start sending back all clients chunked responses, I am trying to find the correct way for clients to request chunked responses.

The current approach I am thinking to make the decision to send back chunked response if client has the header "Accept-Encoding: chunked" or probably use a custom header. I read [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) to find the right way to implement this behavior but couldn't find the right way, a client should ask for chunked responses.

Asking for suggestions how this should be handled. Server is built to support HTTP1.1.

Comment: `Accept-Encoding` controls `Content-Encoding` not `Transfer-Encoding`. A client cannot specifically request chunked, or not, but if it specifies version 1.1 in the request line it MUST (in the RFC2119/BCP14 sense) _support_ receiving chunked, thus the server can choose whether to use it. This is clearly stated in RFC2616 3.6.1, although that RFC is superseded by 7230 particularly 3.3.1 and 4.1. That does not mean the client must support _streaming_ though; it could read the entire body using chunked before processing it. Conversely it could stream a partially-transmitted content-length body.

Comment: Only the sender controls the transfer encoding. If the sender knows the length of the data up front, then the sender will specify that length in the data in a header, and will send the data without chunking. If the sender doesn't know the size up front, the sender will use chunking, so it can start sending immediately, without having to buffer the full content first. That's what chunking is for, and has nothing to do with streaming.

Comment: Both of your comments makes sense, I called out streaming here as I think streaming can be implemented in HTTP 1.1 by chucked transfer. So basically I was thinking to implement multipart over chunked transfer. Multipart providing me with some data schema and chunked transfer some kind of a streaming of that data.